# Any command to get big query execution plan?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-bigquery

Is there any way out to get query execution plans in big query and it's performance analysis.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

BigQuery now has a query explanation built into the web UI. This is what I think you're after.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE 2021**

This is possible now. From CLI:

```
$ bq show -j --format=prettyjson FULL_JOB_ID
```

[API Call](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/get):

```
GET https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/{projectId}/jobs/{jobId}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not currently. The BigQuery execution plan wouldn't necessarily look like what you expect; since there are no indexes, the query engine doesn't have to pick a strategy based on what it thinks are the best keys / indexes to use.

That doesn't mean that there will never be an explain plan; we do realize the value of understanding the performance characteristics of a query. If you'd like to track the issue, feel free to file a feature request here: https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `dryRun` is what you are interested for. From https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs, search for dryRun:

> [Optional] If set, don't actually run this job. A valid query will
>   return a mostly empty response with some processing statistics, while
>   an invalid query will return the same error it would if it wasn't a
>   dry run. Behavior of non-query jobs is undefined.

If you have the DryRun flag set to true, it will return statistics about your query, so "totalBytesProcessed", without running your query, if the query is valid, and the same error that you would normally receive if the query is invalid